# Assign value of PerformanceCounter to label in WPF Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF application that I would like to provide CPU usage details from within the application (the application reporting on itself). I have a working console application that allows me to monitor any Application, I wanted to know if it was possible to use this same logic for`PerformanceCounter`to update a `Label` or `TextBox` with the information from `PerformanceCounter`.

**Code for CPU usage - console application:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a Application to monitor");
        appName = Console.ReadLine();

        PerformanceCounter myAppCPU =
         new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", appName, true);

        Console.WriteLine("Press the any key to stop ... \n");

        if (myAppCPU != null)
        {
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                double pct = myAppCPU.NextValue();
                Console.WriteLine("CPU % = " + pct);
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No Process found");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I fail to see what the actual question is, but yes you would be able to get the `PerformanceCounter` values within a `WPF` project and provide the values up to the `UI`. Is there a specific reason that you are unable/see that you'd be unable to get the value up to the UI?

Comment: @StephenRoss, thank you for replying. I am trying to figure out how I would go about showing the raw CPU usage information within my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    //Create the Performance Counter for the current Process
    PerformanceCounter myAppCPU = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, true);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Initialize a timer
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
        //Check the CPU every 3 seconds
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        //Start the Timer
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    //Every 3 seconds the timer ticks
    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Write the result to the content of a label (CPULabel)
        CPULabel.Content = $"CPU % = {myAppCPU.NextValue()}";
    }
```

With `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` you can get the process name
of your Application.

Create a Timer that ticks every x Seconds. In the Timer event read the next CPU value and write it to a label directly (like in my example) or to a Property that is binded to you view.